# Does this series diverge or converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers s.t. 
$a_n≤a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$. Does the sum over $a_n$ converge or diverge?

I've played around with the inequality and believe that the sum diverges, but can't seem to find a rigorous proof. I used the counter example $a_n=n$ to show it doesn't converge.

Comment: Try $a_n=-\frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n=n$ then, yes, it diverges. And if $a_n=0$, then it converges. So, there is no universal answer.

Comment: Ok. In that case, what if we had to restrict each $a_n$ to being strictly positive?

Comment: @kam Under that extra hypothesis, I don't know the answer.